# strassen's matrix multiplication algorithm implementation in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, strassen

I was trying to figure out how to implement this algorithm in javascript but I got really confused in this part:

> Divide the input matrices A and B and output matrix C into n/2 * n/2 submatrices.

Can anyone help?

Comment: in JS matrix does not exists, so please provide an interpretation od matrix meant by the exercise

Comment: Ciao @Berto99, `let array[4][4]` it's equal to a matrix 4 by 4.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito yep, but it is an array of array, now if you want the four n/2 * n/2 matrix, then you should need a tons of arrays, so here where my question comes from

Comment: The trick is to avoid copying sub-matrices around. When you say "divide the input matrices A and B and output matrix C into n/2 * n/2 submatrices" you don't actually create smaller matrices and copy the data -- you leave the matrices embedded inside their larger matrices and work with them in place. You can check out https://github.com/wcochran/strassen_multiplier/blob/master/mm.c to see a version I wrote in C.